# To find if entered no. is prime or not. The output i am getting is quite weird

Tags: c, for-loop, primes

Following is the code i have written to find if the entered no. is prime or not. please tell what to correct as the output is coming quite weird.

```
` #include<stdio.h>
  main()
 {
   int n,i;
   printf("enter a no.");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
   {
        if(n%i==0)
        printf("its prime");
        else{
               printf("not prime");
             }
   }
}
```

[The output is shown in the picture below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDj4K.png)

Comment: The output in the image exactly matches what your code produces. What exactly is your question? (And an image of your entire IDE was not necessary, BTW; learn to capture the output of single windows. Graphics larger than necessary are unreadable on mobile devices and are quite unfair to those users who pay for the data on those devices.)

Comment: I simply wanted the system to tell me if the no. entered was prime or not. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: p.s. sorry for the larger image.

Comment: No, it is **you** to tell what is wrong with your code. This is not consulting or debugging service. And you shall not post images, but include the text in your question! Learn [ask].

Comment: There are a couple bugs in this code.  Here's a hint for one of them:  If the number is 15, and you check if you can divide by two, and see that you can't, you will immediately declare 15 to be prime, when clearly it is not.  Actually I have that backwards, because your "prime" and "not prime" cases are backwards.  A number is not prime if you *can* divide it by a factor, not the other way around.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain **specifically** what the problem is with the code you've posted and ask an actual question. *Where did I go wrong?* is not a valid question here. **Be specific**, and don't expect us to figure out what you're asking or guess what you want us to help you with. It's YOUR JOB to clearly describe the problem and ask the question if you want us to help you. Please do so with an [edit] to your question, not by dropping hints in the comments.

Comment: @Olaf Stack Exchange gives me an option to post images for answerers like you to get a better understanding of the question asked. And i am just a novice trying to figure out the problem with my code. If you do not intend to answer, then fine. Stop being rude unnecessarily.

Comment: @ChayanKathuria: Read [ask]! Site rules require an answer to be self-contained. Thus mean it has to include all relevant information **in the question itself**. Not in an external screenshot or a link! Just as a highway gives you the option to u-turn and drive the wrong direction does not mean you are allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you don't understand how modulo works. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation),  the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (sometimes called modulus).

When you ask `if(n%i==0)` you're asking if `n` when divided by `i` gives a remainder 0 or not. Take `n=6` and `i=3`. Then `n%i==0` evaluates to "TRUE", because 6 is divisible by 3. Your algorithm tries to print the number is prime when it's quite the opposite. The following code should work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
  main()
 {
   int n,i;
   printf("enter a no.");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
   {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            printf("not prime");
            return 0; //Since you've already proved it's composite, there's no need to waste time.
        }
   }
  printf("Number is prime."); //If your number is not prime, this line won't execute as your program will exit with that return statement.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the answer getting printed multiple times, then you should not print the answer statement inside the for loop. Alternatively, make the use of the 'break' statement.
Also, make your prime-checking conditions correct.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
    int n, x;

    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (x = 2; x <= n / 2; x++) {
        if (n % x == 0) {
            printf("Not prime");
            break;
        }

        else {
            printf("Prime");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```